# glDebugMessageCallback on OSX / XCode 5

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl

I can't find the function [`glDebugMessageCallback()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDebugMessageCallback.xhtml) in any of the OpenGL headers for OS Mavericks / XCode 5. The OpenGL context is 4.4, so it should be present (its been in since 4.3). I'm using GLFW. Any ideas where I might get access to it?

Comment: OSX has only [implemented](https://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/) (up to) OpenGL 4.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the official information from Apple, the highest supported OpenGL version in OS X 10.9 is OpenGL 4.1:

https://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/

You can also confirm this by looking the OpenGL header, which is located at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl3.h`. It contains definitions inside version specific preprocessor conditions, and the highest I see is this (starting at line 2269):

```
#ifndef GL_VERSION_4_1
#define GL_VERSION_4_1 1
...
#endif
```